# Translating key from Keys enumeration to ScanCode and VirtualKey

Tags: c#, winapi, keyboard, keypress

I have list of Keys elements in my `List<Keys>` which I capture in

```
private void KeyboardHook_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {}
```

method, and now I'm facing a problem - I need to simulate a press all of these keys, so my idea is to use `keybd_event(VirtualKey, ScanCode, 0, 0);` to simulate key down, but I have no idea how to get VirtualKey and Scan code when all I have is Keys enum object. `SendKeys` is not an option, because I need them to press them simultaneously, not each after last.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already noted, your enumeration is VirtualKey codes.
To get the scan code, you need to call `MapVirtualKey(vk, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC)` WinAPI.